# Installed Ubuntu 14, Monitor shuts off at boot

Tags: 14.04, boot

My machine is an ASUS X200MA laptop.

I originally had a dual boot setup with Windows 8/Ubuntu 14, but demands from work and class required me to increase the memory allocated to my Ubuntu half and I decided to just go full Ubuntu.

After the installation from a bootable USB, which went smoothly, I rebooted to finish the installation. After the reboot I would always be presented with a blank screen that eventually would lead to my monitor turning off, seconds later the sound from the Ubuntu login could be heard.

Originally, editing the boot options in grub to change "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" resulted in the same problem, but after attaching an external monitor to the VGA port this solution does work, but with the laptop monitor and not the external one in the VGA port.

The most current update is that the "nomodeset" solution now works without any external monitor plugged in. Pretty sure I must've overlooked something, because that's very strange.

Comment: The bongo drum could actually be the greeting sound of the login screen, and your installation be fine except the video card issue. Can you get into the BIOS of your device, and do a recovery boot with installation media? You can typically boot existing installations with the grub from the install media.

Comment: The fact that Ubuntu is fine and the display is the issue had just occurred to me this morning. Yes, as it turns out I can enter BIOS by holding DEL. I'm not certain about the recovery boot, do you mean Ubuntu in recovery mode? I was able to eventually boot Ubuntu recovery mode, then go to root shell and update, upgrade, and put the ppa x-swap repository. But all that got me right back to where I was, no display and the Ubuntu noise. The ASUS X200M has integrated Intel graphics, if that helps at all.

Comment: Ok, that is good news so far. In case you did boot into recovery mode with the grub bootloader that was installed, you could just try to boot your regular configuration, but pass the boot parameter "nomodeset" to the kernel.

This can be done by navigating to the entry that represents your normal boot in the grub menu, and then press the "e" key.

There will be a lot of text on your screen, and somewhere in there you'll find "quiet splash", replace that with "nomodeset" and press F10 to boot with the edited setting.

With some luck, your screen might come up then, and we can work from there.

Comment: This is curious. In the past, the 'nomodeset' solution had done nothing for me. However, this time around I plugged an external monitor into my VGA port and did exactly as you said. The external monitor does not respond, but having it plugged in results in the main laptop monitor working under your solution.

Comment: That is indeed curious, does it work without the external monitor plugged in as well? Some other kernel parameter combination you can try is "acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor". Since the external monitor does seem to make a difference, does your laptop have a hotkey combination to switch display from external, internal and both? You could try what happens if you press the hotkey.

Comment: It could have been a fluke, unplugging the monitor cable didn't ruin anything. I'm currently using the laptop with no external monitor.

Comment: My understanding from reading previous posts is that this is not a permanent solution. Is that correct? I'm assuming I need to do something related to the video driver from this point.

Comment: Well, it is most likely not the best solution, but it can be made a permanent solution, as you can change your grub configuration to always pass this parameter on boot. I'll post this as an answer below, in the meantime you might edit your thread title to be more specific about the issue, and update your question with our findings so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our conversation above, here is what you can do to permanently add the "nomodeset" parameter:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that says GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, and insert the parameter there just like you did with temporarily altering the command line, for example add it after the "quiet" parameter that most likely is there.

Now update the grub configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot the system, your parameter will be automatically added at boot.

Comment: Just wanted to update that since having this work I have downloaded Intel Linux Graphics Installer. It took a bit of time to install the drivers, but when it was done I accepted an automatic update for Ubuntu and now everything works fine, no "nomodeset" needed.  Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem. Thanks, bgse for all your help.

Comment: So, this fixed my issue at boot, but now closing my monitor shuts the laptop down rather than sleep/suspend.